# Imprimir un numero después de cada 4 clicks en el boton(Tkinter) Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Buen dia, Estoy intentando imprimir 1 numero despues de un numero determinado de veces en que se hayan presionado el boton.

Ejemplo:
Por defecto 1

Después de presionar 4 veces el botón, Imprime 2

Después de presionar 4 veces el botón, Imprime 3

Y así consecutivamente hasta el 10.

Hasta el momento solo tengo esto que me imprime del 1 al 10 por cada click en el botón. Espero puedan ayudarme gracias!

```
ventana = tkinter.Tk()
ventana.geometry("600x500")

def pri():
    global i
    if i > 10:
        i = 1
    print(i)
    i+=1
i = 1

boton = tkinter.Button(ventana, text="Compila pls",command=pri, width="30", height="2", bg="#00CD63")
boton.place(x=22, y=320)
ventana.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es realmente sencillo, yo lo que te sugiero es crear una variable auxiliar para llevar tu contador:

```
ventana = tkinter.Tk()
ventana.geometry("600x500")
i = 1
clic = 0
def pri():
    global i, clic
    clic += 1
    if clic >= 4: 
        clic = 0
        if i > 10:
            i = 1
        print(i)
        i+=1

boton = tkinter.Button(ventana, text="Compila pls",command=pri, width="30", height="2", bg="#00CD63")
boton.place(x=22, y=320)
ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder,  y gracias por la sugerencia. Tengo una duda en tanto el código, Si quiero que el primer click imprima 1, Que modificación debería hacer?

Comment: Inicia clic en 4 y el primer clic imprime 1, luego de 4 clics imprimira 2, y así sucesivamente.

Comment: Muchas gracias!